# Транслитерация текста из <textarea> при нажатии <checkbox>

Tags: javascript, html

Есть поле для ввода текста и чекбокс. Когда чекбокс выбран, все буквы должны поменяться с кириллицы на латиницу.

**Вопрос:** Как реализовать транслитерацию текста?

**Код:**

```js
function send() {
  var text = document.getElementById('text').value;
  var check = document.getElementById('trans').value;
  let trans = new Array();
  trans['А'] = 'A';
  trans['а'] = 'a';
  trans['Б'] = 'B';
  trans['б'] = 'b';
  trans['В'] = 'V';
  trans['в'] = 'v';
  trans['Г'] = 'G';
  trans['г'] = 'g';
  trans['Д'] = 'D';
  trans['д'] = 'd';
  trans['Е'] = 'E';
  trans['е'] = 'e';
  trans['Ё'] = 'Yo';
  trans['ё'] = 'yo';
  trans['Ж'] = 'Zh';
  trans['ж'] = 'zh';
  trans['З'] = 'Z';
  trans['з'] = 'z';
  trans['И'] = 'I';
  trans['и'] = 'i';
  trans['Й'] = 'Y';
  trans['й'] = 'y';
  trans['К'] = 'K';
  trans['к'] = 'k';
  trans['Л'] = 'L';
  trans['л'] = 'l';
  trans['М'] = 'M';
  trans['м'] = 'm';
  trans['Н'] = 'N';
  trans['н'] = 'n';
  trans['О'] = 'O';
  trans['о'] = 'o';
  trans['П'] = 'P';
  trans['п'] = 'p';
  trans['Р'] = 'R';
  trans['р'] = 'r';
  trans['С'] = 'S';
  trans['с'] = 's';
  trans['Т'] = 'T';
  trans['т'] = 't';
  trans['У'] = 'U';
  trans['у'] = 'u';
  trans['Ф'] = 'F';
  trans['ф'] = 'f';
  trans['Х'] = 'H';
  trans['х'] = 'h';
  trans['Ц'] = 'Ts';
  trans['ц'] = 'ts';
  trans['Ч'] = 'Ch';
  trans['ч'] = 'ch';
  trans['Ш'] = 'Sh';
  trans['ш'] = 'sh';
  trans['Щ'] = 'Sch';
  trans['щ'] = 'sch';
  trans['Ъ'] = '\'';
  trans['ъ'] = '\'';
  trans['Ы'] = 'I';
  trans['ы'] = 'i';
  trans['Ь'] = '\'';
  trans['ь'] = '\'';
  trans['Э'] = 'E';
  trans['э'] = 'e';
  trans['Ю'] = 'U';
  trans['ю'] = 'u';
  trans['Я'] = 'Ya';
  trans['я'] = 'ya';
  trans['«'] = '\"';
  trans['»'] = '\"';
  trans['-'] = '-';
  trans['—'] = '-';
  trans['№'] = '#';
  trans['`'] = '\'';

  var result = '';
  for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if ((check === 'on') && (trans[text[i]] != undefined)) {
      result += trans[text[i]];
    } else {
      result += text[i];
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('text').value = result;
}
```

```html
<form name="msg" method="POST" id="form" action="message.php">
  <input type="checkbox" name="translate" id="trans" /> Транслитерировать
  <p><label>
                <textarea name = "message" style = "height : 50px; width : 50%;" id = "text" placeholder = "Введите сообщение..." onkeyup="schet()" value = ""></textarea>
            </label></p>

  <p id="chars"></p>

  <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Сохранить" /></p>

</form>
```

Comment: Советую вам какой нибудь апи для переводов подключить (например гугл транслейтс), потому что это дичь))

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Но мне не нужен перевод, мне нужен транслит...)))

Answer (score 0):

Не видно, где запускается `send()`

У вас переменная заполняется `trans`, a смотрится `transl`.

И смотрите хром/инструменты-разработчика (F12); там наверняка ошибку видно.

---

И еще:

Короче конструировать объект:

```
const trans = {
  'А': 'A', 'а': 'a',
...
```

Если нет переприсвоений, лучше использовать `const`, a не `var/let`.

Используйте `"use strict"`.

Answer (score 0):

Вот вам пример, без чекбокса и тд конечно, но думаю вы логику поймете

```js
let textAreaValue = document.querySelector('textarea').textContent

let trans = []
                trans['А']='A';     trans['а']='a';
                trans['Б']='B';     trans['б']='b';
                trans['В']='V';     trans['в']='v';
                trans['Г']='G';     trans['г']='g';
                trans['Д']='D';     trans['д']='d';
                trans['Е']='E';     trans['е']='e';
                trans['Ё']='Yo';    trans['ё']='yo';
                trans['Ж']='Zh';    trans['ж']='zh';
                trans['З']='Z';     trans['з']='z';
                trans['И']='I';     trans['и']='i';
                trans['Й']='Y';     trans['й']='y';
                trans['К']='K';     trans['к']='k';
                trans['Л']='L';     trans['л']='l';
                trans['М']='M';     trans['м']='m';
                trans['Н']='N';     trans['н']='n';
                trans['О']='O';     trans['о']='o';
                trans['П']='P';     trans['п']='p';
                trans['Р']='R';     trans['р']='r';
                trans['С']='S';     trans['с']='s';
                trans['Т']='T';     trans['т']='t';
                trans['У']='U';     trans['у']='u';
                trans['Ф']='F';     trans['ф']='f';
                trans['Х']='H';     trans['х']='h';
                trans['Ц']='Ts';    trans['ц']='ts';
                trans['Ч']='Ch';    trans['ч']='ch';
                trans['Ш']='Sh';    trans['ш']='sh';
                trans['Щ']='Sch';   trans['щ']='sch';
                trans['Ъ']='\'';    trans['ъ']='\'';
                trans['Ы']='I';     trans['ы']='i';
                trans['Ь']='\'';    trans['ь']='\'';
                trans['Э']='E';     trans['э']='e';
                trans['Ю']='U';     trans['ю']='u';
                trans['Я']='Ya';    trans['я']='ya';
                trans['«']='\"';    trans['»']='\"';
                trans['-']='-';     trans['—']='-';
                trans['№']='#';     trans['`']='\'';

let res = ''

setTimeout(() => {
  textAreaValue.split('').forEach(l => {
    res += trans[l]
    console.log(res)
  })
}, 3000)
```

```html
<textarea>привет</textarea>
```